# Why equations of one variable which n instance of it appeared is unsolvable without "going higher order"?

Tags: functions

The following may seemed to be a painfully simple question that might have a deep reason. Consider the following:

\begin{align}
x+x+x+x+x=9 & \text{ vs } 5x=9\\ 
xxxxx=9 & \text{ vs } x^5=9\\
x^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}=9 & \text{ vs } {}^5x=9
\end{align}

All of the equations on the left have the common property that no rearrangement of $x,9$ and the existing operators and their inverse ($+,*,\wedge$ respectively) can solve it. All equations on the right have the common property that it can be solved in one step by applying the inverse operator.

We also knew that in any equations, if all variables are in powers of one, then the equation is linear, otherwise it is nonlinear.

1. What exactly is the nature of the inverse operator for the right equations that allow them to solve an otherwise unsolvable equation. Is it expressible in terms of the operators in the left equations, is it in some sense a nonlocal operator?
2. How to prove that (other than brute force all possible rewritings) that the left equations cannot be solved without invoking the operators on the right equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing naming an operation with knowing how to compute its values, or the values of the inverse operation.

Your first equation is just the fact that multiplication is defined as repeated addition (at least at the elementary level we're discussing). That doesn't mean you can actually calculate $x + x +x + x + x$ any other way, until you've studied repeated addition and discovered some algorithms. You can't solve $5x = 9$ until you've studied fractions. Just calling it "division" doesn't really provide an answer.

For exponentiation as repeated multiplication the inverse problem is even harder. Writing $\sqrt[5]{9}$ just gives the solution a name. There's no way to calculate it other than some kind of brute force numerical method.

Inverting tetration is even harder.